# Collision Detection With Objects In Other ArrayLists, While Ignoring Objects In Their Own

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, collision-detection, game-physics

I am creating a bullet-hell-esque, space shooter-y, type of game from scratch in JavaFX. Something along the lines of the Raiden series.

For a little bit of background on what I currently have set up:

I have three array lists. One for the player character, one for the enemy characters, and one for the projectiles. All of the objects in these array lists come from subclasses of a parent class named, "Entity." That is, the player character, enemy character, and projectile classes are all children of "Entity."

Now, every time the game creates one of those entity objects, it gets added to its respective array list.

Example:

```
//"playerEntities" is the array list
//"playerCharacter" is the object being added
private void addPlayerCharacter()
    {
        PlayerCharacter playerCharacter = new PlayerCharacter();

        playerEntities.add(playerCharacter);

        gameArea.getChildren().add(playerCharacter.getTempCharacter());
    }`
```

I then check for collision detection between any of the two objects by comparing their bounds and current coordinates. If the objects intersect, they are removed from their respective array lists.

Example:

```
@Override
public void checkCollision()
{
    if((!Game.playerEntities.isEmpty()) && (!Game.enemyEntities.isEmpty()))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Game.playerEntities.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < Game.enemyEntities.size(); j++)
            {
                Entity firstEntity = Game.playerEntities.get(i);
                Entity secondEntity = Game.enemyEntities.get(j);

                if(firstEntity.location.x < secondEntity.location.x + (secondEntity.width) &&
                        firstEntity.location.x + (firstEntity.width) > secondEntity.location.x &&
                        firstEntity.location.y < secondEntity.location.y + (secondEntity.height) &&
                        firstEntity.location.y + (firstEntity.height) > secondEntity.location.y)
                {
                    Game.playerEntities.remove(firstEntity);
                    Game.enemyEntities.remove(secondEntity);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Even though I am checking that the array lists have at least one element in them before they can be compared, I am still getting these sorts of exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
etc...
```

It should be noted that the objects on-screen ARE disappearing as they should once a collision has been made.

I can't figure out how the array lists can be empty when they can't even be called to check for a collision in the first place without the objects existing, or how the objects can be removed from on-screen without their obvious existence in the array list and a collision being registered.

My main goal with this is to allow like-typed entities to not collide with each other, while collisions are detected between opposite types. That is, the enemies will pass through each other without being deleted, but will collide with the player character and the player character's projectiles. Is there any easier way I can achieve this, or fix my current method? I've tried messing with this for several hours now and I'm starting to get frustrated.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Answer (score 0):

It simple... Take this example.

player.size == 3
enemy.size == 5

and is so happens that player nr 3 intersects with enemy nr 4.
You then remove player 2, and now player.size == 2, enemy.size == 4;
i == 3, j == 3.
That causes the loop to continue, trying to compare player(3) with enemy(3). player 3 does not exist and will cause an array out of bounds.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Game.playerEntities.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < Game.enemyEntities.size() && i < Game.playerEntities.size(); j++)
        {
            Entity firstEntity = Game.playerEntities.get(i);
            Entity secondEntity = Game.enemyEntities.get(j);

            if(firstEntity.location.x < secondEntity.location.x + (secondEntity.width) &&
                    firstEntity.location.x + (firstEntity.width) > secondEntity.location.x &&
                    firstEntity.location.y < secondEntity.location.y + (secondEntity.height) &&
                    firstEntity.location.y + (firstEntity.height) > secondEntity.location.y)
            {
                Game.playerEntities.remove(firstEntity);
                Game.enemyEntities.remove(secondEntity);
            }
        }
    }
```

The alteration in the inner loop's condition should solve your problem. You could also possible introduce a "continue":

```
for(int i = 0; i < Game.playerEntities.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < Game.enemyEntities.size(); j++)
        {
            Entity firstEntity = Game.playerEntities.get(i);
            Entity secondEntity = Game.enemyEntities.get(j);

            if(firstEntity.location.x < secondEntity.location.x + (secondEntity.width) &&
                    firstEntity.location.x + (firstEntity.width) > secondEntity.location.x &&
                    firstEntity.location.y < secondEntity.location.y + (secondEntity.height) &&
                    firstEntity.location.y + (firstEntity.height) > secondEntity.location.y)
            {
                Game.playerEntities.remove(firstEntity);
                Game.enemyEntities.remove(secondEntity);
                continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this wont work because you are removing some objects :

```
Game.playerEntities.remove(firstEntity);
Game.enemyEntities.remove(secondEntity);
```

so Id do the following:

- remove index based
- always remove backwards
- remove after checking collisions :

  ```
  List<Integer> indices_to_remove_player=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> indices_to_remove_enemies=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ```

  and then, the code in your collision checking if has to be :

  ```
  indices_to_remove_player.add(i);
  indices_to_remove_enemies.add(j);
  ```

  after the for-loops :

  ```
  for (int r=indices_to_remove_player.size()-1; r >= 0; r++) {
       Game.playerEntities.remove(indices_to_remove_player[r]);
  }
  for (int e=indices_to_remove_enemies.size()-1; e >= 0; e++) {
       Game.enemyEntities.remove(indices_to_remove_enemies[r]);
  }
  ```

Logically, thats the only way : Imagine, there are three ships crashing :

- a player with enemy1 **and** enemy2

  - v this way you go in Jake's solution
  - v ^enemy1 with the player - **wont be removed if going backwards**
  - v ^enemy2 with the player - **wont be removed when you follow Jake's 
    solution**
  - ^ this way you go if inverting the for-loops

Now, you are detecting the collision between the player and enemy1. Both are removed. Now enemy2 isnt removed, just because its at a later position in the list, and so the player isnt there anymore, even if both ships are crashing with the player at the same time.
**Note :** Probably it will also work if you 'invert' your loops :

```
i=Game.playerEntities.size()-1; i <= 0; i++
j=Game.enemyEntities.size()-1; j <= 0; j++
```

But then youll have the problem I mentioned before, just that now the first objects come last, so enemy2 and the player will be removed, but not enemy1.
If you are having any questions about this, feel free to comment.
Hope this helps.